# Nginx allow only *.domain.ac.in for POST, DELETE, PUT requests

Tags: nginx

How do I configure nginx server to allow only *.domain.ac.in domains for POST, DELETE and PUT requests methods with basic authentication enabled. GET should be accessible to everyone in the world

Comment: What have you done till now? Show the work and ask about the issues you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this config:

```
if ($request_method != GET) {
    limit_except GET POST DELETE PUT{
        allow 192.168.1.0/32; #put network of *.domain.ac.in domains here
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Note that allowing the GET method makes the HEAD method also allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Elvis Plesky

Based on your inputs I have done the following and its working.
In **allow** variable instead of network range cant' I say ***.domain.ac.in domain.ac.in** because network range might change so I want to refer to only domains

> ```
>   limit_except GET {
>        allow   192.168.33.1/24;
>        deny    all;
>        auth_basic           "Login required";
>        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
>   }
> ```